# Error Code 400 sending emails from VBA using the MS Graph API

Tags: vba, ms-word, microsoft-graph-api

I registered an app in Azure|Entra ID, and recorded the Tenant ID, Client ID and Client Secret.

I tested them by sending an email via the graph API using PowerShell.

I want to send emails from VBA using the MS Graph API.

I am developing the macro in Word as I do not have Access.

I get:

> Status Code: 400 bad request “Message:/me” request is only valid with delegated authentication.

[My app permissions.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MQ0t.png) Some have been installed on a 'poke and hope' basis.

Answer (score 1):

I may of fixed it, I changed the endpoint from

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/sendMail
```

to

```
..../users/sendMail
```

That got rid of the 400 error. However, I now have a message telling me that my JSON is not correct!!

Thank you for looking

Comment: "_My JSON is not correct_" - That sounds like a new question, so this comment does not belong in an answer (this part of Stack Overflow is strictly a Q&A site, not a forum). However, to get you started, you can check your JSON (which you have not shown us) in any decent online checker - for example, [this one](https://jsonlint.com/). If that is not sufficient to help you solve your own problem, then you can ask a new question - but please bear in mind [ask]. If you do share JSON in a new question, be sure to remove any sensitive data - and show a [mre].

Comment: I was not asking a new question HERE. I was giving my solution and then identifying the next layer of the problem. Yes, I did raise a seperate question and quickly got useful information. Now I am onto the next layer of the problem, which I will not even mention here! Just for information a correctly formatted VBA JSON string evaluates to Invalid JSON due to the escaped quotes that are a 'feature' of VBA.

Comment: Fair enough - I agree you were not explicitly asking a new question. But would your answer be any less complete or any less useful to future visitors if the "_However..._" sentence was removed? It's a very minor point - but the Q&A format of Stack Overflow strives to avoid such distractions (see the [tour]). And I'm glad your follow-up question was resolved.